# How do I get negative exponent?

Tags: exponentiation

I am trying to get negative exponent expression to work. Say I have 1.3 * 10^-3

I tried putting that between \$$ pair and got the following

$$1.3 * 10^-3$$

I see 10-3 instead of seeing -3 in superscript

Thanks

Comment: You need brackets. 10^{-3}

Comment: And you might want to use `\times` instead of `*` : $1.3 \times 10^{-3}$.

Comment: @MrTopology I searched and couldn't find it online. The MathJax tutorial didn't have it either. Ultimately it would be a good idea to add this to the tutorial, but could you post your comment as answer?

Comment: @fahadash: The very first sentence in the MathJax tutorial is: "To see how any formula was written in any question or answer, including this one, right-click on the expression it and choose **Show Math As > TeX Commands**." So all you have to do is browse these pages looking for a negative exponent, then right-click on it.

Comment: Use `1.3\cdot10^{-3}` between those two dollars. And BTW, this question belongs in http://tex.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: This question is about TeX/MathJax. It is not about mathematics, so I think it is off-topic and should be closed. This is a bit unfortunate given that it surely helps many users making most of MathJax. But them's the breaks. Mind you, TeX systematically uses braces to enclose multicharacter material into a single item.

Comment: Of course it is in the tutorial. Point 5.

Comment: @barakmanos it does not really belong on tex.se

Comment: @quid Thank you. I see it now. I tried positive exponents and they worked just fine to I assumed negative would too hence my question.

Comment: Sorry for posting it to the wrong site. I don't want to delete the question and remove the comments you guys spent time writing. Unless you are okay with it? If not, feel free to close my question.

Comment: @quid: Dunno, but that's where I would post it.

Comment: I added this to [the tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Closing. Oops, it was already there but as a separate item.

Comment: @barakmanos the question as written is clearly a meta question. It asks about how to write it here. It does not even mention any particular typesetting software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get more than two "symbols" in the exponent, you need the brackets {...}.

Then you get $10^{-3}$ by 10^{-3}

Keep in mind, that you always need these brackets, when you want to put more symbols in the exponent, or index.

For example $x_{12}$ by x_{12}